# SQL Server への接続を確立のエラーが発生しました

Tags: sql, sql-server

以前ローカルのSQL ServerへSSMSから
アクセスできましたが、できなくなりました

対応方法を教えてください

SQL Server への接続を確立しているときにネットワーク関連またはインスタンス固有のエラーが発生しました。サーバーが見つからないかアクセスできません。インスタンス名が正しいこと、および SQL Server がリモート接続を許可するように構成されていることを確認してください。 (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - 指定されたサーバーまたはインスタンスの位置を特定しているときにエラーが発生しました) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9640142.html

Answer (score 0):

接続指定を以前はlocalhost、今はIPもしくはサーバー名で指定してないでしょうか？「SQL Server がリモート接続を許可するように構成されていることを確認してください。」は外部から接続する際にTCP/IP経由の設定していなければ該当のエラーが表示されます。